# Migration play from 2.2 to 2.3: No implicit view available from Any

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3, anorm

Try to migrate my project from play 2.2.7 to 2.3.8.

The project has the following code:

```
def setCoordinatesOfAddresses(cardId: Long, caller: Option[Tuple2[Float,Float]] = None, event: Option[Tuple2[Float,Float]] = None) {
  Logger.debug("callling SC.setCoordinatesOfAddresses")
  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    try {
      val query = SQL("Execute Sc.setCoordinatesOfAddresses {cardId}, {deviceLatitude}, {deviceLongitude}, NULL, NULL, {eventsLatitude}, {eventsLongitude}")
      query.on(
        "cardId" -> cardId,
        "deviceLatitude" -> caller.map(_._1).getOrElse(null),
        "deviceLongitude" -> caller.map(_._2).getOrElse(null),
        "eventsLatitude" -> event.map(_._1).getOrElse(null),
        "eventsLongitude" -> event.map(_._2).getOrElse(null) ).execute()
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => Logger.error("error", e)
    }
  }
  Logger.debug("SC.setCoordinatesOfAddresses called")
}
```

And compiler gives me this error:

```
Error:(384, 28) Play 2 Compiler: 
  ../app/controllers/Cards.scala:384: No implicit view available from Any => anorm.ParameterValue.
       "deviceLatitude" -> caller.map(_._1).getOrElse(null),
                     ^
```

What should I do to solve this problem?
As I understand from documentation, I need to define parameter types. But I can't understand where and how to do that, in following code.

Comment: Have you tried any of these answers?

Comment: I had this issue and the reason was because I was using java 1.7 and not 1.8, which the latest (2.4) version of uses.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
val ps = Seq[anorm.ParameterValue](yourParameter1,yourParameter2) // Seq[ParameterValue]
SQL("SELECT * FROM test WHERE a={a} b={b}").
  on('a -> ps(0), 'b -> ps(1))
```

You are using parameter of `Any`(or someother) type but the doc says to use `anorm.ParameterValue` type

[Source](https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/Play20/blob/master/documentation/manual/Migration23.md#anorm)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to first try `val p: ParameterValue = caller`.

I think the issue is more that there is no specific parameter conversion for `Tuple2[Float,Float]` (btw `(Float, Float)`).

Before Anorm 2.3, unsafe conversion was using `.toString` (which can lead to a lot of issue).

The better is to convert the tuple to a formatted string, either before passing it as parameter or by adding a custom parameter conversion.

(Anorm doc indicates type safety issues, and how to implement conversion)

Answer (score 0):

The `getOrElse(null)` is causing your problem. This is because you're calling `getOrElse` on an `Option[Float]`. However `null` in Scala cannot be assigned to a value type like `Float`. From the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Null):

> Null is a subtype of all reference types; its only instance is the null reference. Since Null is not a subtype of value types, null is not a member of any such type. **For instance, it is not possible to assign null to a variable of type scala.Int**.

The same statement applies to `Float`. Since `null` and `Float` do not have a common super-type (other than `Any`), Scala infers the `caller.map(_._1).getOrElse(null)` as `Any` instead `Float`. This was allowed in Play 2.2.x, however in 2.3.x, `Any` is no longer allowed to be passed as a parameter because it is not type safe.

The solution? Just remove the `getOrElse(null)`s and you're good to go. `caller.map(_._1)` is an `Option[Float]` which Anorm knows how to handle whether it's empty or not. In general, using `null` in Scala is bad practice. If you see yourself calling `getOrElse(null)`, you should ask yourself if perhaps there's a better way to handle it safely.